# Trigger webpacker compile when file outside javascript folder changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I've run into an issue with webpacker in my rails app during development. Webpacker should also compile when some of the related config files change, but doesn't since they aren't in the `app/javascript` folder.

**Is there to have webpacker also watch additional files for changes?**

More detailed:
I load my css through webpacker. For this I'm using TailwindCSS and postCSS. I tend to change the tailwind config file (located in the application root) quite a bit, to automatically generate additional utilities and/or variant. 
However, when I change the tailwind config file it doesn't trigger webpacker to recompile on the next page load. It only recompiles when I change one of the files in the `app/javascript` folder - even if it is just adding an extra blank line. I would like to avoid having to manually trigger webpacker to recompile.

I have changed nothing to the Rails defaults for webpacker.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/webpacker.yml`, you want to add files and directories to the `resolved_paths` section.

```
resolved_paths:
  - app/assets
  - tailwind.config.js
```

There’s more information in this article https://rossta.net/blog/why-does-rails-install-both-webpacker-and-sprockets.html